# Changing the Values with Specific Character from Data Frame in R

Tags: r, lapply, gsub, character-replacement

My data frame like this.

```
    X           Y              Z 
    10.5 m³/s   15. m³/s    14.3 m³/s
    10. m³/s    11. 5m³/s    16.7 m³/s
    10.8 m³/s   15.7 m³/s    1.5 m³/s
```

I have to delete some specific characters from my data frame. In order to overwhelm this issue i have wrote some code like this.

```
  df[] <- lapply(df,gsub, pattern='. m³/s', replacement='')
```

It seems to be worked. But i encountered with "." issue which is orginally being shape of the data.

```
X      Y       Z 
10.5   15.     14.3
10.    11.5    16.7
10.8   15.7    1.5
```

As well as I did every combination for the pattern function.

I need double values so i have to delete points just where placing at end of the values.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: You need to add `fixed=TRUE` to your `lapply` I believe.

Comment: It didnt worked

Comment: Is this value a typo? `11. 5m³/s` (note space between "." and "5").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can account for the decimal in the whole number values by adding a regex `\\.?`, which matches literal "." if present one or zero times.

```
d <- data.frame(X = "10.5 m³/s", Y = "15. m³/s", Z = "14.3 m³/s")
lapply(d, gsub, pattern='\\.? m³/s', replacement='')

$X
[1] "10.5"

$Y
[1] "15"

$Z
[1] "14.3"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked. I was forget it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `readr::parse_number()` is also an option?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), readr::parse_number))
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
      X     Y     Z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  10.5  15    14.3
2  10    11    16.7
3  10.8  15.7   1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(across(X:Z,~as.double(str_remove_all(.x, " |m³/s"))))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
      X     Y     Z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  10.5  15    14.3
2  10    11.5  16.7
3  10.8  15.7   1.5
```

Input:

```
structure(list(X = c("10.5 m³/s", "10. m³/s", "10.8 m³/s"), 
    Y = c("15. m³/s", "11. 5m³/s", "15.7 m³/s"), Z = c("14.3 m³/s", 
    "16.7 m³/s", "1.5 m³/s")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```